# recursive binary search using python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, recursion

Wrote this code in comp sci class and I cant get it to work, it always returns as false every time I run it. Its supposed to be a recursive binary search method... Any idea why it only returns false?

```
arr = [1,10,12,15,16,122,132,143,155]

def binarysearch(arr,num):
    arr2 = []
    if (len(arr) == 1):
        if (arr[0] == num):
            return 1
        else:
            return 0
    for i in range (len(arr)/2):
        arr2.append(0)
    if (arr[len(arr)/2]>num):
        for x in range (len(arr)/2,len(arr)):
            arr2[x-(len(arr)/2)]=arr[x]
        return binarysearch(arr2,num)
    if(arr[len(arr)/2]<num):
        for x in range(0, len(arr) / 2 ):
            arr2[x] = arr[x]
        return binarysearch(arr2, num)



num = raw_input("put number to check here please: ")
if(binarysearch(arr,num)==1):
    print "true"
else:
    print "false"
```

Comment: You aren't searching the right half of the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing vastly more work than you need to on things that Python can handle for you, and the complexity is masking your problems.

- After your base case, you have two `if` statements, that don't cover the full range—you've overlooked the possibility of equality.  Use `if/else` and adjust the ranges being copied accordingly.
- Don't create a new array and copy stuff, use Python's subranges.
- Don't keep repeating the same division operation throughout your program, do it once and store the result.
- If you want to print `True/False`, why not just return that rather than encoding the outcome as `0/1` and then decoding it to do the `print`?
- Recall that `raw_input` returns a string, you'll need to convert it to `int`.

The end result of all those revisions would be:

```
def binary_search(arr,num):
    if (len(arr) == 1):
        return (arr[0] == num)
    mid = len(arr) / 2
    if (arr[mid] > num):
        return binary_search(arr[:mid], num)
    else:
        return binary_search(arr[mid:], num)

num = int(raw_input("put number to check here please: "))
print binary_search(arr,num)
```

Comment: thank you for the help, but for some reason whenever I try to run this code I end up always getting "false" again... tried to  change it a bit to get it to work but so far I am unsuccessful

Comment: I had hardwired test cases so I could stay in my editor.  As such I didn't note that you were comparing a string to the numbers in the array, which won't work.  Now fixed.

Comment: Yep... thanks a lot, just before seeing your comment I used a line by line debugger and after a while saw that I used raw_input instead of input... it works now. Thank you